# In regex difference betewen \\G and ^

Tags: java, regex, string

I see from this [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/bounds.html) that these two boundary matches are quite similar:
`\G` and `^`.

I have also seen the example of `\G` that they have shown at the end of the same [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/bounds.html).

```
    Enter your regex: dog 
Enter input string to search: dog dog
I found the text "dog" starting at index 0 and ending at index 3.
I found the text "dog" starting at index 4 and ending at index 7.

Enter your regex: \Gdog 
Enter input string to search: dog dog
I found the text "dog" starting at index 0 and ending at index 3.
```

It's very clear compared with no boundary matchers, however what about:

```
Enter your regex: \Gdog 
Enter input string to search: dog dog
I found the text "dog" starting at index 0 and ending at index 3.
```

vs

```
Enter your regex: ^dog 
Enter input string to search: dog dog
I found the text "dog" starting at index 0 and ending at index 3.
```

What is the subtle difference between the 2?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This explains about \G

https://forums.oracle.com/thread/1255361

\G start its searches from the start of the string and keep searching after the first match is ended.

^ will only give one result as the search ends if the match is found at the beginning of the search

Comment: Unfortunately the link https://forums.oracle.com/thread/1255361 is broken.

Answer (score 3):

It is as described in the javadocs:

> \G - The end of the previous match
>
> ^ - The beginning of a line

Try the sentences like `dog`, `dogdog`, `dogdogdog`, etc. with both `\G` and `\^`. `\G` will find matches for the dog's in different positions while `^` will only find the first one.

As for you query why `^` and `\G` are similar for the sentence `dog dog`. It is because the first match for `\G` will be from index `0 to 3` the second match will start from index `3` onwards which is `<space>dog` and not `dog` thus the second match fails.